# Take away comma from lists inside a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list `[["H", "E", "L", "L", "O"], ["B", "Y", "E"]]`
Whitch I need to covert to: `["HELLO"], ["BYE"]]`

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with `''.join`:

```
x = [["H", "E", "L", "L", "O"], ["B", "Y", "E"]]
[''.join(y) for y in x]
```

out:

```
["HELLO"], ["BYE"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join()` and list comprehension for this.

```
l = [["H", "E", "L", "L", "O"], ["B", "Y", "E"]]
new_list = ["".join(i) for i in l]
print(new_list) # ['HELLO', 'BYE']
```

Answer (score 1):

try this;

```
["".join(b) for b in a]
```

another way:

```
list(map("".join, a))
```

output:

```
# a = [["H", "E", "L", "L", "O"], ["B", "Y", "E"]]
# print(list(map("".join, a)))
['HELLO', 'BYE']
```

Answer (score 1):

As everybody suggests the comprehension, this is a good use case for `map` as we have a function readily available:

```
lst = [["H", "E", "L", "L", "O"], ["B", "Y", "E"]]

[*map("".join, lst)]
# ['HELLO', 'BYE']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably make a new list like below:

```
test_list = [["H", "E", "L", "L", "O"], ["B", "Y", "E"]]
test_list2 = []


for i in test_list:
    test_list2.append("".join(i))
```

Comment: That is what we do in ```list``` comprehension. This is just a traditional loop

Comment: I'm not an expert at list comprehensions, that's why I used for loop

Comment: Nor problem. As you start to expand your knowledge more you will start to use list comprehensions